# Delete checkbox all in Checkbox menu Primefaces

Tags: jquery, primefaces

i want to delete the option of select all in the component of primefaces (SelectManyCheckbox).
[image]

I'm trying of delete class of the div for jquery.

$('.ui-chkbox ui-widget').remove();
        $('.ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default').remove();

help me please.

I sorry for my english. this is bad.

Comment: where you trying to delete it?In the browser for any testing purpose or in your code?If In your code post relevant code to that part

Comment: i want to delete for my code. modidy the component.

Comment: @Macro R.. So you want to delete for example `scarface`?can you post your by seeing the issue and images I am having  very hard time understanding your actual issue?

Comment: Hi SrinivasR, my issue is delete select all of this component. you understading my issue now? thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-panel .ui-selectcheckboxmenu-header .ui-chkbox-box{
display: none;
}
```

just use css to hide that options, however, I don't think remove an components default element is a good choice

Comment: thanks you for you solutions, I'm agree with you, but select all of this component not have event listener  or you know how to make event has. Sorry for my english.

Comment: A bit late, but selectAll does have an event called toggleSelect:
  <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" listener="#{bean.listener}"    update="@form" />